# Why are these strings evaluated to be unequal?

Tags: python, string, vim

Here is the vimscript x.vim:

```
python << endpy
import vim
import time
import os
cb = vim.current.buffer
bufferString = '\n'.join(cb[:])
with open(cb.name, "r") as currentFile:
    fileString = currentFile.read()
print bufferString
print "================="
print fileString
if bufferString != fileString:
    print "File changed!"
else:
    print "Nothing changed!"
endpy
```

Open the script in vim and type `:so %`, and it prints out the file and the buffer, and according to python, they are different, but by eyeballing, you can see they clearly equal. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file you have read might have a newline at the end of the last line. However, getting the lines from `vim` and joining them with `\n` will *not* have a newline at the end of the last line.

Comment: If the file was edited in vim (which seems to be very likely) it will almost assuredly have a new line at the end because vim puts one there by default.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the answer.  Try adding `+ '#'` to the two `print` lines.  Or print out `len(fileString)` and `len(bufferString)`.